# Is it compusory for a family member of EU citizen to provide information of accomodation in Irish visa application?

Tags: visas, accommodation, ireland

I am applying for Irish short stay visa as a family member of EU citizen. Is it necessary to write the accommodation details in Irish application.According to Directive 2004/38/EC, it is not required by the family members of EU citizen.The other fact is,we did not decide yet regarding accommodation. My husband who is an EU citizen will also travel with me.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it should not be necessary to provide accommodation details.  If the application requires you to enter something, you could write "to be arranged."

Comment: Can I write NA in address section and 00 in phone # required. As it is an online application ,I can't move to next page without answering  *asterisk questions.  .

Comment: @FatimaKhan I would probably do that.  Are you sure you selected the correct "reason for travel" as the spouse of an EU citizen ("Family member of EU/EEA/Swiss cit. (spouse)")?  If not, change the reason for travel or start over with the correct reason for travel.

Comment: Yes I selected the correct reason "Family member of EU/EEA/Swiss cit. (spouse)"